# How to create(sign_up/registration) user in Devise + Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, doorkeeper

Created rails api with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [Doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper), with all default configuration nothing fancy attribute in User model. 
How to registration a user using api ? What are default attributes?

Tested below via direct post but get ROLLBACK

```
POST "//users" 
 Parameters: {"registration"=>{"email"=>"name@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
POST "/users"

```
Parameters: {"registrations"=>{ "email": "name@gmail.com", "password": "the-provided-password","password_confirmation": "the-provided-password_confirmation" }}
```

registrations not a registration

Comment: Started POST "//users" for 127.0.0.1 
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"registrations"=>{"email"=>"name@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "registration"=>{"registrations"=>{"email"=>"name@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}

   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK